# Draw lines between points in Maple

Tags: math, plot, curve, maple

In Maple I have two lists

```
n:=10:
A:=[seq(i, i=1..n)];
B:=[10, 25, 43, 63, 83, 92, 99, 101, 101, 96];
```

I want to plot the values

```
plot([seq([A[i], B[i]], i=1..n)]);
```

It works, but the lines between the points are not curved.

If I draw a line using these points in Excel, it will interpolate the values between the points and draw a nice and smooth curve.

This must also be possible to do in Maple, but I cannot find the options to do this.

If I look in options in the documentation http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=plot%2foptions, I see that I probably need to use the argument `style`. The doc says `The styles line, polygon, and polygonoutline all draw curves by interpolating between the sample points`, but it doesn't draw the curves even if I use `style=line`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to do it (below), but it's not an option to **plot**. The command **plot** uses linear interpolation. Usually the number of points being plotted is large enough that this is sufficient. To get a higher-order interpolation, use **CurveFitting:-Spline**, like this:

```
plot([CurveFitting:-Spline(A,B,x), zip(`[]`,A,B)], x= 1..10, style= [line, point]);
```

Notice that there are separate sections of the above command for plotting the curve and plotting the points themselves.